# Cpu input type question

Tags: command-line, make

I am trying to configure node libs

```
make -j4 # adjust according to your available CPU capacity
```

If I write 1000 is it 1 ghz?Is it mghz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, `-j` does not mean MHz it specifies how many compile processes should be startet in parallel. So you should put the number of cores available for this option or maybe number of core + 1.

Depending on the compile task, it can be that there is a lot disk IO which would slow down the complete compile process when a too high `-j` as it would put much more IO on your storage system.